# Rails "Class.new \"

Tags: ruby, backslash

I saw this whilst browsing the code for the [acts as commentable with threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration/templates/comment.rb) gem

```
new \
  :commentable => obj,
  :body        => comment,
  :user_id     => user_id
```

From testing it out in the console, it looks like the backslash allows you append attributes on a new line, so that they're all aligned. Is there any more to it than that?

What's this idiom/technique called? Searching for rails backslash doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is exactly what you think it is. `\` at the end of a line lets you continue your expression on the next line.

I am not sure if this has an official name ("multiline statement" maybe?).

PS: While looking for a name I was browsing the rubinius parser code. The `\` skip code is implemented [here](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-melbourne/blob/a799f21c70336b312b8dd3f77e8a9d28dbf602f0/ext/rubinius/melbourne/grammar.y#L4064).